# Why nonparametric maximum likelihood of mixture is convex

Tags: optimization, nonparametric, convex, nonparametric-bayes

Consider $x_i \sim N(\mu_i, 1)$ where $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and assume $\mu_i$ is generated i.i.d. from an unknown distribution $F$. We are interested in estimating the unknown $\mu_i$. One way to solve the problem is by nonparametric maximum likelihood as follows.

$$\min_{F\in \mathcal{F}} - \sum_{i=1}^n log \int \phi(x-\mu)dF(\mu)$$where $\phi$ denotes a standard normal distribution and $\mathcal{F}$ is a convex set.

As claimed in many places without explaination ([ref1](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v082i08/v82i08.pdf#page17), [ref2](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/%7Emizera/Preprints/brown.pdf), [ref3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02011.pdf#page17)), this is a convex optimization problem. Why? The integrand is a mixture and it is not clear to me how this becomes convex. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional $J : \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex if the space $\mathcal{F}$ is convex and if $J(tf + (1 - t)g) \le tJ(f) + (1 - t)J(g)$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$ and all functions $f, g \in \mathcal{F}$. For notational simplicity, let $L_x$ denote the functional $$L_x (F) = \int \phi(x - \mu) dF (\mu)
$$ and let the functional of interest be denoted by

$$J(F) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \left( -\log \int \phi(x_i - \mu ) dF(\mu) \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^n  (-\log L_{x_i} (F) ).$$

Here we have a sum of a convex and non-decreasing function ($-\log$) of a linear functional ($L_{x_i}$), which together make $J$ a convex functional. The functional $L_{x_i}$ is linear because the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int f(x) dg(x) $ is linear in $g$, i.e. that $\int f(x) d(g + h)(x) = \int f(x) dg(x) + \int f(x) dh(x)$ ([See these notes for proof](https://people.math.sc.edu/sharpley/math555/Lectures/RS_Properties.pdf)).

To show that $J$ is convex, start by noting that $-\log \circ L$ is convex, because
\begin{align}
-\log (L_{x_i} (tF + (1 - t)G)) &= -\log (t L_{x_i}(F) + (1 - t)L_{x_i}(G)) \quad \text{ (by linearity)} \\
&\le t(-\log L_{x_i}(F)) + (1 - t)(-\log(L_{x_i}(G)) \quad \text{ (by Jensen's Inequality)} \\
\end{align}

Since this inequality holds for all $x_i$, sum up the $n$ inequalities you get from each of the $L_{x_i}$ to get
$$
J(tF + (1 - t)G) \le t \sum_{i = 1}^n (-\log (L_{x_i} (F))) + (1 - t) \sum_{i = 1}^n (-\log (L_{x_i} (G))) = t J(F) + (1 - t) J(G)
$$
which proves that $J$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure, the set of all probability distributions is convex, so for any probability distribution function $F$, $J(F)$ is convex. So as in the papers listed, they discretize $F$ into a finite linear combination of fixed point masses, i.e. $F = \sum w_i \delta_i$ where $\delta_i$ is the point mass at grid point $i$, and they solve for $w_i$ by maximizing $J$. This is a convex optimization problem because the discretized $F$ is just a linear combination of probability mass functions. However, if we do not fix the grid, then it is not a convex problem any more. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "for any probability distribution function $F$, $J(F)$ is convex." If $F$ is fixed, then $J(F)$ is a number, not a function, and it does not make sense to say it's convex. A function cannot be convex unless its domain is convex, so before you can talk about whether $J$ is convex you must specify its domain. The space of all cdfs is convex, but this certainly does not imply that any subset of that space is convex.

Comment: The Stieltjes integrals $\int \cdot dF$ strongly suggest the functions $F$ being considered in this problem are cumulative distribution functions (cdfs), but a function of the form $\sum w_i \delta(x - x_i)$ is a probability mass function (pmf), and are typically given lowercase names. If you want to consider pmfs of the form $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i \delta(x - x_i)$, then the corresponding cdfs are step functions of the form $F(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{j(x)} w_i$ where $j(x) = \#\{ i \in [1:n] : x_i \le x \}$, assuming that the "grid points" $x_i$ are in ascending order.

Comment: To prove that this space of cdfs is also a convex set, consider taking any two functions from this space and ask if their convex combination is still in the space. In this case, it is easier to work with the pmfs: take two finite linear combinations of Dirac deltas (point masses), say $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i \delta(x - x_i)$ and $g(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n u_i \delta(x - x_i)$. The convex combination $tf(x) + (1 - t)g(x)$ will still be a finite linear combination of Dirac deltas, and the associated cdf will be a step function of the appropriate form, proving that the space is convex.

Comment: In fact, the "grid" does not need to be fixed for the problem to be convex. The same argument as above with functions on different "grids" still works: let $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i \delta(x - x_i)$ and $g(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^m u_i \delta(x - y_i)$. A convex combination of these is still a finite linear combination of Dirac deltas on the new "grid" $\{ x_i \} \cup \{ y_i \}$, which is still finite. So even if the grid is not fixed the domain is still convex; however, it will not be finite dimensional or closed, which are serious hurdles to numerical computation in a computer.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry about my confusion. This has been very helpful. So working with the point mass here actually preserves the convexity. As in [Feng & Dicker 2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02011.pdf#page27), it claims eq (4) as a convex problem while eq (3) is not convex because it is a finite mixture model. Now I believe that the space of a mixture of nonparametric and a unimodal parametric is still convex, i.e. $f(x) = w g(x) + (1-w) \phi(x;\theta)$ where $g(\cdot)$ is any probability density and $\phi(\cdot)$ is a unimodal parametric probability density with parameter $\theta$.

Comment: For example, $\phi(\cdot)$ can be a standard normal density. However, if it is a mixture of nonparametric and multiple unimodal parametric densities, then the multi-modal will destroy the convexity just like other finite mixture models.

Comment: Any thought on the mixture $f(x) = wg(x) + (1-w) \phi(x;\theta)$ where $g(\cdot)$ is any probability density and $\phi(\cdot)$ is a unimodal parametric probability density with parameter $\theta$? Do you think this kind of mixture is still convex? Thanks.